# how to use this lib barcode scanner?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar

**Solved**

Finally I solved it. You can find my code [Here](https://github.com/dxd-bleed/Barcode-Scanner-Android)

This is specific to [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner)  lib. I want detail explanation on how to add it in my project and use either of zxing or zbar.

As instructed `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7'`
 is giving gradle project failed while syncing.

I have added that lib inside libs/barcodescannerLIB

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include  ":libs:barcodescannerLib:core", ":libs:barcodescannerLib:zxing:zxing", ":libs:barcodescannerLib:zxing:sample", ":libs:barcodescannerLib:zbar:zbar", ":libs:barcodescannerLib:zbar:sample"
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dxd.testbs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/libs'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(":libs:barcodescannerLib:core")
    compile project(":libs:barcodescannerLib:zxing:zxing")
    compile project(":libs:barcodescannerLib:zxing:sample")
    compile project(":libs:barcodescannerLib:zbar:zbar")
    compile project(":libs:barcodescannerLib:zbar:sample")

}
```

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?

Comment: " is giving gradle project failed while syncing" -- the Gradle console (in Android Studio) or your terminal (for command-line builds) should be giving you more specific information about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Error:(12, 0) Could not find property 'supportLibraryDependency' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@75b6d24e.

Answer (score 0):

**Add in your build.grandle file the support dependence:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```